# How to check status of hardware components in Linux?

Tags: command-line, hardware, lshw

I know commands like `lshw` and `dmidecode`, but all they do is list the detected hardware attributes, right? I can get all the information I want about the hardware in my computer.

But I would also like to check if that device which has been detected is working properly or not.

`flathub`…`hw-probe` from flatpak does the work,
but it dumps the info into its online database/repo. 
[This](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=345221877d) is an example of it.

Is there any way I can save this offline or redirect its output to somewhere else I like?

Is there any tool which can do the same work offline?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to upload the results to the Linux hardware DB; use the `-show` and `-verbose` options, then save the result locally to `file`:

```
sudo -E hw-probe -probe
sudo hw-probe --show --verbose > file
less file
```

`man hw-probe`:

> ```
> -show
>    Show devices info.
> -verbose
>    Use with -show option to show type and status of the device.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use

```bsh
$ sudo hw-probe -get-inventory-id -email ADDR
Inventory ID: INVENTORYID

$ sudo -E hw-probe -all -upload -inventory-id INVENTORYID
Probe for hardware ... Ok
Reading logs ... Ok
Uploaded to DB, Thank you!

Probe URL: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=PROBEID

WARNING: You'll get a letter soon to confirm new node.

$ sudo hw-probe -import ./DIR -i INVENTORYID
Computer COMPUTERID
Importing probe PROBEID
Created index: ./DIR/index.html
```

Comment: if i have to import the info from the above url? how would the command go for that?

Comment: @ZeeshanHaris I explained it all in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install `perl-JSON-XS` package and then:

```
sudo -E hw-probe -all
sudo cat /root/HW_PROBE/LATEST/hw.info/devices.json
```

See computed device statuses in the output:

```
"pci:10de-0dfc-1028-1535" : {
  "Bus" : "PCI",
  "Class" : "03-00",
  "Device" : "GF108GLM [NVS 5200M]",
  "Driver" : "nouveau",
  "SVendor" : "Dell",
  "Status" : "works",
  "Type" : "graphics card",
  "Vendor" : "NVIDIA Corporation"
},
"pci:1217-8221-1028-0535" : {
  "Bus" : "PCI",
  "Class" : "08-05-01",
  "Device" : "OZ600FJ0/OZ900FJ0/OZ600FJS SD/MMC Card Reader Controller",
  "Driver" : "sdhci_pci",
  "SVendor" : "Dell",
  "Status" : "detected",
  "Type" : "sd host controller",
  "Vendor" : "O2 Micro, Inc."
},
...
```